# Storing bookmarks in a markdown file, how could I encode tags?

Tags: git, markdown, bookmarks

I am a long time user of bookmarks and I would like a fresh start with a simple text based system that can be archived and merged in git. I started storing bookmarks in a markdown formatted file. I have a file called bookmark.md which contains titles and links such as:

```
# Q & A sites
[Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com)
```

Then I convert the file to html with

```
pandoc -s bookmark.md -o bookmark.md.html
```

I have seen [this simple system](https://github.com/skx/bookmarks.public) stores all bookmarks in an html file and stores tags in `<id title="">` tags. For example the tags `photography` and `stackexchange` would be stored in:

```
<li title="photography, stackexchange">
```

What would be the best approach to encode such tags in markdown format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even plain markdown allows you an [optional title tag](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#link)

Just write

```
# Q & A sites
[Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com "photography, stackexchange")
```

and you will get a link with title.

btw: the title tag is probably not the "right" html-tag for tags, but it will work.

Comment: Thanks klml, I would be curious to know if there is a better way to encode such html tags?

Comment: The 'title' [attribute offers advisory information](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#h-7.4.3); so tags are not completely wrong. But internet users would expect a short explaining like ```[Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com "cool software forum")```.

In standard you have to use a [data-attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-html5-20101019/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes). But markdown, fortuntaly, does not support this. 

For [bookmarks.public](https://github.com/skx/bookmarks.public) your markdown and title approach is great.

Comment: Even if it was available in Markdown, I would not like to use the data attribute because it embeds "non-visible data". I would rather have visible tags.